# Stripped male connector from dryer

Tags: pipe, gas

I stripped the threads on the male pipe from my dryer. Now I cannot connect the gas line to my dryer. What are my options to fix this problem? Can I replace the pipe coming from my dryer? Or would it be better to try to re-thread the pipe?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the damaged pipe would help, but either way I'm concerned; DIY gas lines make me very nervous.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I'm nervous too - I'm fine with electric, OK with water/sewer, but I won't touch gas.

Comment: I had help from a registered gas tech and he supervised my work - good learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how badly damaged the pipe is, but it can be re-threaded with a pipe die.  I would replace the pipe nipple coming out of the gas valve.  I would look at how the gas valve is mounted to the dryer before trying to remove the damaged nipple.  Some have poor mounting and could damage the gas valve.  You may need to remove the valve before removing the nipple from it.  With either option, I would test for leaks by spraying soapy water on the joints after you turn the gas back on and looking for bubbles.